# $r$ of the product of two time series as function of $r$s of the individual series

Tags: time-series, correlation

Suppose I have two time series $x_t$ and $y_t$ for times $t \in T$, normalized such that each time series, as well as the set of times, has mean $0$ and variance $1$. Let $r_x$, $r_y$, $r_{xy}$ be the least-squares correlation coefficients of $x_t$, $y_t$, and $x_t y_t$ against time, so the best-fit lines of $x_t$ and $y_t$ are $x_t = r_x t$ and $y_t = r_y t$. Then does knowing $r_x$ and $r_y$ by themselves give any information at all about $r_{xy}$?